# Monitoring Kafka in Python

Tags: python, jmx, apache-kafka, codahale-metrics

I'm adopting Kafka and trying to understand how to monitor it (e.g. is it running out of memory for log storage). I see that it uses Yammer Metrics and exposes them via JMX - this apparently makes sense to people in Java land.

Is there an HTTP API I can build on? Or really any sort of relatively structured output at all?

Answer (score 0):

You can use yahoo's kafka manager to  inspection of cluster state. Download kafka manager @ https://github.com/yahoo/kafka-manager.
Hope it may help you

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out and report back when I get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Kafka monitoring tool for this

https://github.com/impetus-opensource/ankush

You can get the latest release from following link https://github.com/impetus-opensource/ankush/releases.

You can create as well as monitor your clusters using above tool

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out and report back when I get a chance.

Comment: @CharlesOffenbacher: Have you had a chance to check it out? What's your verdict?

Comment: I ended up just monitoring the VMs themselves (via new relic) for hardware usage, and then using Zookeeper and Kafka connections to monitor the actual data flow itself. In the end I didn't want to take a new dependency on Java and another project just for this.